# webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x not work

Tags: ios, swift

If I use this line `webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x = 1000` in `viewDidLoad` it doesn't works. But if I use in `scrollViewDidScroll` it works fine, but I need it to work in another function. Why this happens? How to make this line work in `viewDidLoad` or other functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probaly need to wait for the document to finish loading and set contentOffset in this method of WKNavigationDelegate:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
```

Comment: Even more, I think he needs to wait until the DOM is ready to be able to calculate its height. Basically because the web document won't be rendered before that.